# ADODB.Command: Prepared statement not returning expected number of records

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, mariadb, adodb

I'm using ADODB.Command to execute prepared statements in Classic ASP, however the number of records being return by MariaDB is incorrect, and I can't figure out why.

The code below gives an example of the problem I'm having:

```
<%

    Dim conn, comm, rs, SQL, SQLparam

    set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    conn.Open("DSN=localhost")

        ' Standard execution            

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM tests WHERE ID > 0"

        set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)  

        response.write "<p>Results: " & uBound(rs.getRows(),2) & "</p>"

        ' Prepared statement execution          

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM tests WHERE ID > ?"
        SQLparam = 0

        Set comm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

            comm.ActiveConnection = conn
            comm.CommandText = SQL
            comm.Parameters.Append(comm.CreateParameter("@param",varType(SQLparam),1,250,SQLparam)) 

            set rs = comm.Execute()

            response.write "<p>Results: " & uBound(rs.getRows(),2) & "</p>"

        set comm = nothing

    rs.close() : set rs = nothing   
    conn.close() : set conn = nothing

%>
```

Output:

```
Results: 4433 ' as expected
Results: 10
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. I've played around with the "CreateParameter" settings [as outlined by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017), but the wrong number of records are always returned by MariaDB, never mind what I change.

What's also strange is that if I change the SQL to do a SELECT COUNT, the prepared statement returns the correct count value, it just doesn't return the correct number of rows when I try to select them.

Comment: Show us the resulting SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get the resulting SQL of a prepared statement. This issue has been fixed anyway, it was an incompatible ODBC MySQL connector.

Answer (score 2):

After some further testing this appears to be a driver issue. I'm using MariaDB but with the MySQL ODBC connector (8.0 Unicode Driver). After switching to the MariaDB ODBC connector the prepared statement works as expected. I apologise for not testing further before posting.

I guess MariaDB and the MySQL ODBC connector are incompatible when trying to perform certain database functionality, because up until now I've never had any issues.